# Error while creating search center (Powershell)

Tags: search, powershell

I try to create a new search center (as a subsite of a subweb) with powershell
When I do this, I get an error:

> New-SPWeb : Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site properties for Web at Url: "hosturl/ER/FD/search" OriginalException: The value of AvailablePageLayouts contain
>   s invalid url. All page layout urls inside the string have to be server relative. The url '~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/SearchResults.aspx' ('/ER/_catalogs/masterpage/SearchResults.aspx')is not in th
>   e current site collection '/ER'.
>   At MyScript.ps1:116 char:2
>   +     New-SPWeb -Url $searchUrl -Template "SRCHCEN#0" -Language $web.Language

First I've activated the "PublishingSite" feature on the sitecollection (**ALSO WITH POWERSHELL**) Then I execute this function:

```
function CreateSearchSubsite{
    Param ([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb] $web)

    WriteText " > Start creating a search subsite"
    $searchUrl = $web.Url.TrimEnd('/') + "/search"
    $exists = (Get-SPWeb $searchUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null
    if($exists)
    {
        Remove-SPWeb -Identity $searchUrl -Confirm:$false
    }
    New-SPWeb -Url $searchUrl -Template "SRCHCEN#0" -Language $web.Language
    WriteText " > End creating a search subsite"
}
```

Anybody who knows what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the anwser... To create a enterprise search center, you also need to activate the "BaseSite" sitecollection feature. After activating this one, it all works like expected.